# IntelliJ IDEA shortcut to convert first letter to uppercase?

Tags: intellij-idea

for example

String uuid;
String name;
to 
String Uuid;
String Name;

(This is just an example, the above code may not be the correct convention)

Comment: I don't think IntelliJ IDEA should have this function, it is useless.

Comment: I do think it's useful.

Comment: Agree with @AlesisJoan. Specifically for writing Javadoc in my case.

Answer (score 8):

You can try the [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation) third-party plug-in.

> Provides actions for text manipulation:
>
> - Toggle style (camelCase, hyphen-lowercase, HYPHEN-UPPERCASE, snake_case, SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE, dot.case, words lowercase, Words
>     Capitalized, PascalCase)
> - To SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE (or to camelCase)
> - To snake_case (or to camelCase)
> - To dot.case (or to camelCase)
> - To hyphen-case (or to camelCase)
> - To hyphen-case (or to snake_case)
> - To camelCase (or to words)
> - To PascalCase (or to camelCase)
> - Capitalize selected text

Comment: Note that you can record a macro to compose multiple commands into a new one. For example I created `Paste as type` macro. It performs (1) `Paste`, (2) `EditorPreviousWordWithSelection` (i.e. Ctrl+Shift+Left), (3) `To PascalCase`. For example this will paste `StringBuilder` if you have copied `stringBuilder`. I use this everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to do that without third-party plug-in you can just select the first letter and press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>